# Popups in SharePoint Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, authentication

I created a SharePoint App, but each time I am trying to access it I keep getting pop up authentication window. I am trying also with other apps from the SharePoint store, which makes me think the problem is with the configuration of my app services themselves.

I followed the article: http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx . Is there any extra step to do? It's only on my development environment as I don't want to use O365. I am not connected to internet always.

Environment: SharePoint 2013. windows server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're doing development on your machine, I guess that's a case where you have a loopback check, you can get around this problem in a couple of ways, please refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0).

The easiest one for you would be to just disable it since you're only doing development on your local machine.